# JDBC and RMI classpath conflict in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jdbc, rmi

I am trying to program in java using both jdbc and rmi but i am not able to to run the program without exporting classpath for stub for e.g. if my stub is located "home/java" i need to export it using "export CLASSPATH="home/java" and if i don't export it is throwing following exception :
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GImplement_Stub

Now the problem is when i am exporting the path for the stub may be mysql database path is getting overwritten and it is throwing :
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
though if i am not exporting any path other jdbc programs are working fine.
How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple entries in the CLASSPATH variable and the `-cp` command-line argument separated by the colon character `:`.

However I would *strongly* recommend maven for this job, as it makes building way, way easier than juggling classpaths by hand...